# odoo 11 error when installing module subtype_id

Tags: python, windows, odoo, erp

I am trying to make odoo work in windows 10 but I can not make it work odoo, I have searched a lot to try to solve this error but I can not solve it. I am using:

1. windows 10
2. Odoo 11

/__manifest__.py

```
{
    'name':'aplication',
    'description':'description',
    'depends':['base','website'],
    'data':['views/custom_view.xml']
}
```

/__init__.py

```
import models
```

/models/__init__.py

```
from .custom_model import CustomModel
```

/models/custom_model.py

```
from odoo import models,fields

class CustomModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.model'
    name = fields.Char(string='Name')
```

/views/custom_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <menuitem name="Top Menu" id="custom_top_menu"/>
    <menuitem name="Sub Child Menu" id="custom_sub_menu" parent="custom_top_menu"/>
    <record id="custom_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Child Menu</field>
        <field name="res_model">custom.model</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                Click here to create item !
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
    <menuitem name="Child Menu" id="custom_child_menu" action="custom_action"
    parent="custom_sub_menu"/>

</odoo>
```

The error I get is

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 306, in init_models
    model._auto_init()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 2139, in _auto_init
    new = field.update_db(self, columns)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1945, in update_db
    return super(Many2one, self).update_db(model, columns)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 856, in update_db
    self.update_db_notnull(model, column)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 896, in update_db_notnull
    model._init_column(self.name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 2056, in _init_column
    value = field.default(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\wizard\mail_compose_message.py", line 126, in <lambda>
    subtype_id = fields.Many2one(default=lambda self: self.sudo().env.ref('mail.mt_comment', raise_if_not_found=False).id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I do not know how to fix this error, I've tried everything
So I'm seeing this error is in the mail module, which is in the addons folder

Answer (score 2):

**odoo 11 error when installing module subtype_id**
Hello,
     I tried to install the module which you have been made.This gave the error of "ImportError: No module named 'models'" . So you have to write in **init**.py file like this....

***from . import models***
 this will solved your error.

you ask about an error in mail module this is caused by your another custom module in your path. there is no other error in this module.so check your other custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your `/__init__.py`, import all python files in the `models` folder by

```
from . import models
```

Then in `/models/__init__.py` import your custom_model.py file by

```
from . import custom_model
```

Every time you add new file in `models` folder, you have to add it in your `/models/__init__.py` file.